# Google map blinking while listening to location

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Make a simple map tracking with Xamarin form, bu the map kept blinking:

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetCurrentPosition();
        }
        public async void GetCurrentPosition()
        {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            locator.PositionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                var map = new Map(
                MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                    new Position(e.Position.Latitude, e.Position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)))
                {
                    IsShowingUser = true,
                    HeightRequest = 100,
                    WidthRequest = 960,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                };
                var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
                stack.Children.Add(map);
                Content = stack;
            };

            if (!locator.IsListening)
            {
                await locator.StartListeningAsync(1000, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

> How can I solve it?

Comment: You are adding a Map to the StackLayout on every PositionChanged event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal. It's because everytime the location is updated, you create a new map that you add to the page (hence the blinking). Instead, you should keep the same instance of your map and update the position of this map.

You can try this:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {        
        private Map _map;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _map = new Map
            {
                IsShowingUser = true,
                HeightRequest = 100,
                WidthRequest = 960,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
            var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
            stack.Children.Add(_map);
            Content = stack;
            GetCurrentPosition();
        }
        public async void GetCurrentPosition()
        {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            locator.PositionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                _map.MoveToRegion(
                MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                    new Position(e.Position.Latitude, e.Position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)));
            };

            if (!locator.IsListening)
            {
                await locator.StartListeningAsync(1000, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```